# Send CSV file from Google bucket to SFTP server using GCP Cloud function NodeJS

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to send a `csv` file to a `SFTP` server using a `Google Cloud Function`.
This means -

`Step 1` - need to Create a `Connection` with the `SFTP Server`

`Step 2`- Pick the `csv File` from the `GCP Bucket`

`Step 3` - `Push` the File to `SFTP Server` in a certain location

This is the `nodejs` script I am using -

```
exports.helloWorld = (req, res) => {
  let Client = require('ssh2-sftp-client');
  let sftp = new Client();

sftp.connect({
  host: process.env.SFTP_SERVER,
  username: process.env.SFTP_USER,
  port: process.env.SFTP_PORT,
  password: process.env.SFTP_PASSWORD
}).then(() => {
  return sftp.list('/public');
}).then(data => {
  console.log(data, 'the data info');
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err, 'catch error');
});
};
```

And this is my `Package.json` file

```
{
  "name": "sample-http",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.0",
    "@google-cloud/bigquery": "5.10.0",
    "@google-cloud/storage": "5.18.0",
    "ssh2-sftp-client": "7.2.1"
    
  }
}
```

Now Everything runs fine but it doesn't do anything.
Can anyone point to me what script I am missing here and if there is any `documentation` to do the following steps??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the SFTP code is all async, your function is probably returning before the `.then()` has run and your execution environment is ending before the it gets to upload the file. You should make your `helloWorld` function async and await and return a response before returning:

```js
exports.helloWorld = async (req, res) => {
  // ...
  await sftp.connect({
    // ...
  });
  res.send(200);
  res.end();
};
```